# Need to debug both asp and silverlight solutions together

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, silverlight

I have two solutions, one is asp.net and another one silverlight solution. Both of them are hosted on my local server. What I need is to debug two solutions simultaneously, in asp solution i have page with a code like that

```
<iframe src="http://localhost/UI_RegInc/UI_RegInc.aspx?UserId=<%=UserId%>"
    frameborder="0" height="620" scrolling="no" width="1000" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">
</iframe>
```

Here i'm calling UI_RegInc silverlight application, where UI_RegInc.aspx page is calling silverlight application that i want to debug.
What I tried was to start asp application, then in another instance of VS i launch silverlight applicaton, it is UI_RegInc, and in this instance
 trying to attach it to iexplorer process with asp application. But getting no positive result. Also tried to attach to webdev process.
A cumbersome explanation, but hope will understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your ASP.NET and the Silverlight project to a common solution and the Visual Studio debugger will attach to the Silverlight application automatically while debugging the website project. You cannot attach two separate instances of Visual Studio to the same Internet Explorer instance, so you have to add both to the same solution and debug from there.

You can either add the Silverlight project to your existing ASP.NET solution (right click solution, Add -> Existing Project) or create a new solution for times you want to debug both at the same time (create a new blank solution and add the existing projects, same as before).

Here is the process to configure everything step-by-step after that. You can download this source files to the test solution here:

http://www.singulink.com/ClientFiles/StackOverflow/CrossProjectTest.zip

The projects are as follows:

- CrossProjectTest - Silverlight 4 project
- CrossProjectTest.Web - ASP.NET project that hosts the Silverlight application inside Index.html
- IFrameWebApp - ASP.NET project that has an `<iframe>` pointing to Index.html in the other ASP.NET project

1) In the ASP.NET project that is hosting the Silverlight application, change the settings so it doesn't open a page when debugging and specify a port so that you can always reach it at a known address (which in this case will be `http://localhost:18000`). You don't want it to open a page because the IFrame ASP.NET project has the actual page you want to show. We still want it to hook the debugger into the web server process though, which is where step #3 will come in.

[image: Setting port and start action]

2) Point the `src` attribute of your `iframe` inside the IFrame project at the known address of the page that hosts the silverlight application in the other ASP.NET project, like so:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="http://localhost:18000/Index.html"></iframe>
```

3) Right click on the **solution** file, and select Properties. Under "startup project" you will want to select "Multiple startup projects" and set the start action for both of your ASP.NET projects to "Start".

[image: Setting multiple startup projects]

4) Make sure Silverlight debugging is enabled inside BOTH the ASP.NET projects, especially the IFrame project for this particular scenario:

[image]

5) Set a breakpoint in your Silverlight application, press F5, and everything should launch. Because you set both ASP.NET projects to start, it will fire up both development web servers but only one internet browser, pointed to the IFrame project. I added a breakpoint in the App Startup of the Silverlight project just to demonstrate it getting hit:

[image]

6) Press F5 to continue execution and Silverlight should show up in the IFrame, as can be seen here:

[image]

7) Happily place breakpoints in any of the three projects and Visual Studio will debug all of them!

Comment: Thanks for reply. I added my asp project to solution with sl project, for now i have 3 projects, that is - 1)sl application, 2)asp application which is hosting sl application, 3)asp application that has an iframe calling application which is hosting sl application. So i set app#3 as startup project, but i don't get how to start application hosting sl application. Can you advice how to bind them together?

Comment: Oh, it works as is, could not start them all, because of wrong url in iframe. But sl app still did not hit the breakpoints

Comment: I tested it, definitely works. Updated my answer with screenshots and a download link to the solution used for my tests and screenshots.

Comment: Thank you very much for detailed instruction. Everythihg worked out.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check Silverlight on your Web project that host Silverlighth application.

[image]

Comment: That won't help him debug his Silverlight project that is in a different solution.

Comment: I tried this but as Mike Marynowski said that didn't help me.